# When loading a model with Assimp how can I get the Vertices that correspond to my materials (C++)

Tags: assimp

So what I want to do is render each material 1 at a time. Which means that each Material will have it's own vertices. Is there some kind of function within Assimp when I process a mesh that will tell me which material the vertices belong to.

Of course I would put the position, the normal and the texCoord in the vertex and I need the induces.

Answer (score 1):

There is no query to get these meshes implemented in Asset-Importer-Lib right now. But you can write this easily by yourself:

1. Import your model
2. Check whether there are any meshes loaded
3. Loop over all meshes stored in aiScene
4. Sort them for meshes with the same material index
5. Loop over all vertices of the list of meshes.

I wrote a blog-post about that: [Batch-Rendering for Assimp-Scene](https://medium.com/realtime-rendering-for-fun/simple-render-batching-for-static-assimp-models-12bf3d383f06)